# .NET C# Dataset WriteXml include/exclude columns and adding namespace

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, dataset

I have the following piece of code:

```
if (SqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter RequestDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From RequestTabel", SqlConnection))
    {

        DataSet RequestDataSet = new DataSet("Requests");
        RequestDataAdapter.FillSchema(RequestDataSet, SchemaType.Source, "RequestTabel");
        RequestDataAdapter.Fill(RequestDataSet, "RequestTabel");

        DataTable RequestDataTable;
        RequestDataTable = RequestDataSet.Tables["RequestTabel"];

        RequestDataSet.WriteXml(@"C:\temp\MyDataset.xml");
    }
}
```

This reads the content of a (database) table to a DataSet, when finished reading it will write to an XMl file.

My problem:

- Not all columns should end up in the XMl file, how can I exclude/include columns?
- The XML that WriteXml makes does not include a namespace, how can i add this?

Am i forced to open the XML file after the WriteXml to add the namespace?

- Is it possible to build up the xml using an xsd??

Edit: adjusted the path name :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for 1: change your `SELECT` to only select the columns you need, you can even rename the columns on the fly by using `AS` to define an alias.

As for 2: [`DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) and [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) both have a property called [`Namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.namespace.aspx) (for the `DataTable` property see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.namespace.aspx))which you could set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i always feel stupid when I see answers... :P

Comment: Right now I have the following output: <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<ns0:List xmlns:ns0="http://Schema.name_XML">
  <Item xmlns="http://Schema.name_XML"> but the Item element should also have the ns0 reference, any idea how I could get this?
 <prop>lala</prop>
  </Item>
</ns0:List>

Comment: @PhillipParrin no idea... sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Change your select to `select COL_1, COL_2, COL_4 from RequestTable`.

----- Is it to early in the morning or is that how table is spelled??

Comment: Hehe that's the Dutch version for table :P (tabel) and yes it can be quite typo prone! :D + I can't believe i did not think of that! Do you also happen to know something for the namespace?